# How to control multiple OpenVPN instances on the same server?

Tags: openvpn

We have Centos servers running multiple daemons, up to 3 on each server. I have looked at the the rc.d init scripts and see no way to control the daemons independently. We would really like to be able to restart one tunnel without affecting the others. Is this possible? Where should we be looking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The initscripts in Debian and Ubuntu for openvpn allow single instances to be managed by naming them on the command like:

```
/etc/init.d/openvpn start vpn_name_1
```

and

```
/etc/init.d/openvpn stop vpn_name_2
```

If the script(s) that come with the CentOS openvpn package do not support this then you could perhaps copy the logic from the versions in Debian/Ubuntu (don't copy the whole script though as there may be other distro specific differences to worry about).

Answer (score 2):

We run 3 OpenVPN instances in our setup, and we just use:

> /usr/local/sbin/openvpn /etc/openvpn/1.conf & 
>   /usr/local/sbin/openvpn /etc/openvpn/2.conf & 
>   /usr/local/sbin/openvpn /etc/openvpn/3.conf &

Of course each instance is running on a different port and has different settings and then you can kill each instance separately and start them up without affecting the others.